# How to get lower value in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treemap, treeset

I use `TreeMap` to keep daily stocks of a product as shown below:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < stocks.size(); i++) {
    map.put(i+1, stocks.get(i));
}
```

I use day as key and stock as value:

```
key  | value
------------
1    | 5 
2    | 6 
3    | 8 
4    | 4  <-- need to find lower of this value
5    | 9 
6    | 10 
7    | 8
8    | 3  <-- I need to obtain this
9    | 6 
10   | 4
```

I am trying to get the key of lower(4), which is 8. If there are multiple entries that match, such as in the case of lower(7), I want the key of the first entry, so lower(7) should produce 2, not 9.

However, I cannot go over values and need to use keys. So, how can I do this?

If it is not possible, should I also need to use a `TreeSet` to get lower?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, I also thought that but as there are multiple values, can I use stock values as key?

Comment: If it is not possible, should I use a TreeSet to get lower of a given value in that stock list?

Comment: You mean there can be duplicate values? If so, what should happen if there are multiple 3s?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple stock values as given on the list. In such case, the first value should be returned. So, any idea for that situation? Should I only use TreeMap? Or also TreeSet?

Comment: set does not allow doublication but i do not see you need the key so you can use list and use indexOf method https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object) that return the index of the first occurance  then you get the value in that index minus 1

Comment: what do you mean by "need to catch this entry" ?

Comment: @justsomeone I mean "need to obtain this"

Comment: if this mean the value in the key 8 then using list you can get the value in the index 7 as index start from 0 in list same as array if you look for first occurance of the value 3 then the method i mentioned earlier would help :)

Comment: What would happen if the "lower" value occurred more than once among the values?

Comment: As @DawoodibnKareem has pointed out, Values in your example are **repeated** (e.g. `8`). So first of all what should be the type of result: a `List`, a single value? If you need a single Value, then you need to explain which one should be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the stock value as key, and the day as value. This makes it very easy to use `lowerEntry(4).getValue()` to find the day 8.

However, there can be duplicate values, and you want to find the earliest entry (i.e. with the lowest day number). The tree map obviously cannot have duplicate keys, so we work around this by only storing the earliest entry for each stock value.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = stocks.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    map.put(stocks.get(i), i+1);
}
```

Notice that the arguments for `put` is reversed, and the for loop is also reversed. We start from the end of the list, so that the earliest stock values *overwrite* later ones if they happen to be the same.

Then you can do

```
map.lowerEntry(4).getValue()
```

to find 8.